# use execvp to implement find command

Tags: unix, find, command

How to solve this problem, and why does it happen?

```
char *command[]={"find","-executable","print",">","filename.txt",NULL}
execvp("find",command);
```

find: paths must precede expression: >

Answer (score 0):

You can't obtain redirection this way... When you type `find ... > file.txt` in a shell, `>` and `file.txt` are not arguments of the `find` command. The shell interprets everything you type and extract redirections from your command line, makes the redirection before `exec`ing what remains.

A redirection can be obtain by `dup`ing some file descriptor before `exec`ing. In general this is done after `fork`ing and before `exec`ing :

```
if (fork()==0) {
  f = open("file.txt",...);
  dup2(1,f); // redirects stdout to f...
  close(f);
  exec(...); // open files remains open on exec (by default).
}
```